# Attribute Error at API - module object has no attribute 'UserViewSet' - Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, api, rest, django-rest-framework, django-1.8

Setting up Django Rest Framework -

Using the Quickstart tutorial from http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Users and groups links work as expected. I got to add another link - following the same tutorial using appropriate naming conventions for my app and model and I get the error listed in the Title.

I can comment out users and groups and the employees model will work. I can't get more than one link in the Django Rest framework to work properly. Any ideas? Here is the urls code

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from XXXXXXaccess import views
from employees import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)
router.register(r'employees', views.EmployeeViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you have an ambiguity in your imports. Can you import the name explicitly: from XXXXXXaccess.views import UserViewSet ? Otherwise you will overwrite views with the definition of views from employees, where there is no UserViewSet defined, like the error says.

```python
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from XXXXXXaccess.views import UserViewSet, GroupViewSet
from employees.views import EmployeeViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', GroupViewSet)
router.register(r'employees', EmployeeViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Comment: You could also change the module locally like `from employees.views import views as employee_views`.

Comment: Thank you! That was one of those "duh" moments where I was overthinking it. That worked beautifully! :)